# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, proxy

I am trying to make a simple load from an object from the DB, but i got the error "could not initialize proxy - no Session", Any idea ? Thanks

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.jav a:167)
    org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    com.myapp.domain.User_$$_javassist_0.getLogin(User_$$_javassist_0.java)
    com.myapp.validator.UserFormValidator.validate(UserFormValidator.java:34)
```

---

```
@Component 
public class UserFormValidator implements Validator {

@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;  

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return UserForm.class.equals(clazz);
}

public UserDAO getUserDAO() {
    return userDAO;
}

public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
    this.userDAO = userDAO;
}

@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    User user = (User)getUserDAO().findById(new Integer(1));
    System.out.println ("User -> " + user.getLogin());
}
}
```

---

```
@Transactional
public class GenericDAOHibernateImpl <T, PK extends Serializable>
implements GenericDAO<T, PK> {

public GenericDAOHibernateImpl() {
    super();
}

private Class<T> type;

@Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public GenericDAOHibernateImpl(Class<T> type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public void saveOrUpdate(T object) {
    getSession().save(object);
}

public Object findById(Serializable id) {
     return getSession().load(type, id);
}

protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        ">

<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

<!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
<!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html -->                           
<!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html -->
<!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html -->

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
             p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
             p:configLocation="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"
             p:packagesToScan="com.myapp.domain"/>  

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" 
destroy-method="close" 
p:driverClass="${jdbc.driverClassName}" 
p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}"
p:user="${jdbc.username}"
p:password="${jdbc.password}"
p:acquireIncrement="5"
            p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
            p:maxPoolSize="100"
            p:maxStatements="50"
            p:minPoolSize="10" 
/>


<!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
            p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User extends appEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "LOGIN")
private String login;
@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;


public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}
public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `Related` section on the right. This has been answered before.

Comment: true, Thanks, get() instead of load() !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to add `@Transactional` to the validate method:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    ...
}
```

What happens is that because there is no `@Transactional` annotation, there is no session associated to the method, and each query will run in it's own session that is closed immediately afterwards.

The method `session.load()` always returns a proxy, unlike `session.get()` (see here for [differences between load vs get](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-session-get-and-session-load/)).

So the proxy is returned, but due to the missing `@Transactional` the session that created the proxy is immediately closed. When the proxy is accessed the first time, it's session is closed so we get the 'no session' error.

If you change from `load()` to `get()` that will only partially solve the problem, because if after the get you try to load for example a lazy initialized collection, the exception occurs again.

Adding `@Transactional` to the business method will ensure the presence of the same session for the duration of the method call, and prevent the occurrence of this and other related errors.

Comment: Ups, that's the result after adding @Transactional(readOnly=true) to the validate method

Could not autowire field: private com.myapp.validator.UserFormValidator com.myapp.controller.HomeController.userFormValidator; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.myapp.validator.UserFormValidator field com.myapp.controller.HomeController.userFormValidator to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.bea...

Comment: there seems to be a setter missing  `HomeController.setUserFormValidator()`, on a first look this does not seem related to the use of `@Transactional`