# Failed to lazily initialize a collection of role during conversion of object to json

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson

I am new to spring and while fetching records from a table having relationship with other tables getting this lazily initialling error.
I have read a lot online but not getting a appropriate approach.

**Table1:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class Terminal extends BaseEntity {

@Column(length = 100, unique = true)
private String shortName;

@Column
private short number; // short stores up to 32767 value

@Column
private String description;     

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "terminal_id", referencedColumnName = "uuid")
@Cascade({ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DELETE })
private Set<BusinessHour> businessHour;

 public String getShortName() {
    return shortName;
}

public void setShortName(String shortName) {
    this.shortName = shortName;
}

public short getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(short number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public Set<BusinessHour> getBusinessHour() {
    return businessHour;
}

public void setBusinessHour(Set<BusinessHour> businessHour) {
    this.businessHour = businessHour;
}
```

**Table2:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class BusinessHour extends BaseEntity {

@Column
private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;

@Column
private LocalTime startOfOperation;

@Column
private LocalTime endOfOperation;

public DayOfWeek getDayOfWeek() {
    return dayOfWeek;
}
}
```

**Service Code:**

```
@Service
public class TerminalServiceImpl implements TerminalService {

@Autowired
TerminalRepository terminalRepository;


    Iterable<Terminal> allTerminals = terminalRepository.findAll();
    List<Terminal> terminalList =  new ArrayList<Terminal>();
    for (Terminal terminal : allTerminals) {
        terminalList.add(terminal);
    }
    return terminalList;
}
```

Terminal Repository code:

```
@Transactional
public interface TerminalRepository extends CrudRepository<Terminal, Long> {
}
```

**Code where i got error during debug:**

```
private List<Terminal> updateTerminalList() {
    List<Terminal> allTerminals = terminalService.fetchAllTerminal();
    return allTerminals;
}

public void terminalWrapperRun() {
    try {
       Payload payload = createTerminalPayload(applicationId);
        String json3 = object2Json(payload);
        kafkaRESTUtils.sendServerPayload(json3);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 public String object2Json(Object dataArray) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(dataArray);
}
```

**Error:**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: terminal.model.Terminal.businessHour, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain:
```

Getting  exception while converting fetching object to json. which i found due to proxy object return due to fetch type lazy(which i want to kept as it is).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439306/org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-sessi)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue relates to the LAZY loading of Collections by default by your ORM.

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "terminal_id", referencedColumnName = "uuid")
@Cascade({ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DELETE })
private Set<BusinessHour> businessHour;
```

The @OneToMany annotation has a fetch property which is set to LAZY by default.

```
FetchType fetch() default LAZY;
```

[OneToMany reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html)

This means that it will only be loaded when the data is accessed.  In the case of your example, this will happen when you try to create the JSON string.  By this point, however, you are outside the scope of the ORM session so it does not know how to load the data.

Therefore you have 2 options.

1. Change your annotation to eagerly load the data (which means the BusinessHour Set will be loaded at the same time as the parent object

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
2. perform your JSON generation within an ORM session (I would only really recommend doing this is the first option causes performance issues).

Comment: How would i generate json within an ORM session can you assist.

Comment: Looking briefly at the provided code I think the simplest way to achieve this would be to introduce a Transactional annotation around the method that generates the JSON.  This should perform the code within a required Session.  Having said that I think this would give a misleading representation of the code.  Perhaps before invoking the JSON generation you should introduce a separate method which initializes your businessHour Set using

Hibernate.initialize(terminal.getBusinessHour())

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly this is the kind of error caused by an `Entity` being detached from the `EntityManager` at the time of its use (being it a `Proxy` it cannot perform a database query to retrive the data).

You can use:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
...
private Set<BusinessHour> businessHour;
```

Comment: i dont want to use fetchType as EAGER
Can we have other way to do that

Comment: Why? There is almost no performance penalty and you do not have to complicate things even more. Imho it is a cleaner solution

Answer (score 0):

Using FetchType=EAGER means that any query against your entity will load the whole bunch of annotated entities.

Imho, this is only a sensible action if you are 100% sure that your entity will only be used for your special business case.

In all other cases - like programming a data acess as a library, or accepting different kinds of queries on your entities, you should use entity graphs (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs002.htm) or explicit loading (Hibernate.initialize, join-fetch, see for example  https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/).

If your use case only is the transformation, you have two good options:

- Transform your entity to JSON within a Transactional method (as PillHead suggested)
- Load your entity explicitly with all the entities needed (via entity graphs or Hibernate.initialize) within the transaction, and then convert to JSON where you need it.